# Error message on Microsoft files

Tags: microsoft-office

I have Microsoft Office 2000. Yesterday all my files were fine. Today I cannot open them. They are yellowish orange in color and give this warning:

> This program is unable to run because of missing or corrupt files. Contact your computer manufacturer.

What can I do? This is a business, and I need the files.

Comment: Your windows installation is corrupt

Comment: I'm having the same problem since some automatic updates last night... If you open Word or Excel, you should be able to open the files with the "Open" option. If all else fails, uninstall any updates from the dates 9/11 or 9/12. Hopefully, Microsoft will fix this soon.

Comment: Office 2000 in a business environment? It's been over 13 years since that was released, is there a reason not to upgrade?

Comment: Please be aware of [help/on-topic] "not about" ... "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you given, i don't think anything is wrong with the files, maybe just the office software you have, you might have a virus of some kind that has altered the executable or other important files, no way to know exactly without more information

1. you can move the files to another computer with MS office 2k and test the files
2. you can try installing this free software and see if you can open the files again.
   http://www.openoffice.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I think it I Microsoft's 'updates' that have caused it. There is a workaround which involves right-clicking on the attachment then choosing 'save as' - after which you can open it as a file as per usual from your  hard disk.